# SQLite3 - select query fails with Unicode characters?

Tags: sql, visual-c++, unicode, sqlite

My sqlite3 SELECT query fails if the query contains any Unicode characters. ie, the below query returns `0` instead of the actual count. I am generating the select query using C++/Visual Studio 2010.

```
SELECT COUNT() FROM mytable  where   path = "C:\\sølvgut.txt";
```

When I execute the above query using SQLite Expert editor it working as expected. But in my code I am using a wrapper class CppSQLite3.cpp to execute the query which is causing the issue. In the below code, it getting inside the code else if (nRet == SQLITE_ROW)

```
    CppSQLite3Query CppSQLite3DB::execQuery(const char* szSQL)
    {
       checkDB();

       sqlite3_stmt* pVM = compile(szSQL);

       int nRet = sqlite3_step(pVM);

       if (nRet == SQLITE_DONE)
       {
         // no rows
         return CppSQLite3Query(mpDB, pVM, true/*eof*/);
       }
      else if (nRet == SQLITE_ROW)
      {
        // at least 1 row
          return CppSQLite3Query(mpDB, pVM, false/*eof*/);
      }
      else
      {
            nRet = sqlite3_finalize(pVM);
            const char* szError= sqlite3_errmsg(mpDB);
            throw CppSQLite3Exception(nRet, (char*)szError, DONT_DELETE_MSG);
      }
  }
```

Comment: `"` are not used for strings, use `'`.

Comment: I tried passing the path using single quote, but it didn't work.

Comment: Backslash getting in the way? Do you need to escape it?

Comment: @normalocity, it is escaped as  C:\\sølvgut.txt

Comment: Hm, did I misread it the first time? I only saw a single back slash, I thought. No luck then, I guess?

Comment: thanks to all mycode is not working because sqlite wrapper is not supporting the unicode charaters